# GitLab variable false but job is running

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, cicd, build-pipeline

I'm triggering job via API, passing custom variables.

Here is example request:  `curl -X POST -F token=${TRIGGER_TOKEN} -F ref=${branch} -F "variables[SHOULD_COPY_ASSETS]=false"`

This how job in the .yml file looks:

```
copy-assets:
    stage: copy
    script:
      - echo -e "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" > ./.npmrc
      - npm ci
      - npm run copy-develop-ci
    artifacts:
        paths:
          - assets-shared-tmp
        expire_in: 1 week
    rules:
      - if: $SHOULD_COPY_ASSETS
```

As you can see $SHOULD_COPY_ASSETS was set to false, but this job is running anyway.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`if: $SHOULD_COPY_ASSETS` [checks for the existence of the variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#check-if-a-variable-exists), not its value. You want something like `if: $SHOULD_COPY_ASSETS != "false"`

Comment: Thank you very much! This clears this up.